# How to resolve a url path from outside of MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app and to populate the routes table there's a method like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    ....
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id="" });
   ... etc
}

//and in global.asax it gets called like:
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Now if I call that method from outside the MVC app (in some console app, just to get routes), I would pass a new empty collection, it will be populated with the routes used in the MVC app, but what's use of it? 
Can I based only on collection of routes, recognize the url for given controller name, action and other parameters? (again, from the outside of the web app)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking here. You can access any route outside your app.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add it to MVC app's route table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think routes[0].GetVirtualPath() is what you're looking for. However, you'll have to pass a RequestContext and RouteValueDictionary to it. If a route is not able to handle your input, it will return null

Comment: it's throwing Invalid Operation Exception, and says HttpContex.Current can't be null. But I don't have HttpContext, I'm calling it from a console app

Comment: You can mock it up - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx. However it is an overkill in case you're just trying to look generate URLs out of the Route. A better approach IMHO would be to write the substitution yourself

Comment: yes, I've managed to mock it up using solution from here http://forums.asp.net/t/1819622.aspx/1?Using+MVC+Routing+in+a+console+app

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to be able to generate urls from a route collection in a console app (sitemap generator) and have far too many routes to do simple substitutions.  I ended up writing a wrapper around UrlHelper.GenerateUrl...

```
public class UrlGenerator
{
    protected string Protocol;
    protected string HostName;
    protected RequestContext RequestContext;
    public RouteCollection RouteCollection;

    public UrlGenerator(string protocol, string hostName, Action<RouteCollection> registerRoutes)
    {
        Protocol = protocol;
        HostName = hostName;
        RouteCollection = new RouteCollection();
        registerRoutes(RouteCollection);
        // Construct a request context with as little as possible
        RequestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://x.com", null), new HttpResponse(null))), new RouteData());
    }

    public string GetUrl(string action, string controller, object routeData)
    {
        return GetUrl(action, controller, new RouteValueDictionary(routeData));
    }
    public string GetUrl(string action, string controller, RouteValueDictionary routeData)
    {
        return UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, action, controller, Protocol, HostName, null, routeData, RouteCollection, RequestContext, false);
    }
}
```

Now you can do...

```
UrlGenerator g = new UrlGenerator("https", "myurl.com", RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes);
Console.WriteLine(g.GetUrl("Index", "Home", new { product = "toad-for-oracle" }));
```